# How to use an array in the condition as a filter - Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

```
array_users = ["3581", "3592", "3665", "3730"]

@records = Model.find(
           :all, 
           :order => 'date desc', 
           :group => :date, 
           :conditions => {
                 :client_id => current_user.client.id,  
                 :user_id is present in array_users # <------------------
           })
```

How would one make certain that only the records returned have a `user_id` that is present in `array_users` using Rails 2.3.9?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not running v2.3.14? There's lots of important security fixes between there and v2.3.9.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I was not aware of .14.

Comment: You should definitely ensure that you're using some method to keep updated on new versions, especially since any updates to 2.3 at this point are important security fixes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:conditions => {
  :client_id => current_user.client.id,  
  :user_id => array_users
})
```

See [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions) for all the possibilities with the hash conditions.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfect, and for the ref guide. Great stuff in there.